# Installing Ubuntu on MBP 17" Late 2011

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, macbook-pro

I'm following the directions here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro8-2/Trusty

And it says to follow these directions to set the boot order for display: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2157775.html

Those instructions say:

> When GRUB has loaded, make sure you highlight „Try out Ubuntu“ boot entry and hit the „e“ key to edit the boot line in order to fix broken graphical output with standard options. Add the following lines after „load_video“:

What is the ,,e" key?

Answer (score 1):

The key to be pressed is the regular <kbd>E</kbd> on the keyboard, which starts GRUB's *Edit Mode*.

The *Edit Mode* is useful if you want to temporarily over-ride settings in your /boot/grub/grub.cfg or append something (like a kernel option), to the end of a line in a boot stanza just for one boot-up.

When you get this screen -

[image]

Press <kbd>E</kbd> -

[image]